# How do I use dd command for destination size greater than source file size?

Tags: dd

I generated a fairly huge sized file using /dev/urandom. I know urandom is slow. I use these files for some IO verification. When I need a new file of a bigger size, I have to again create the file using urandom, which slows me down.

What I basically want is:
Use the same file to create destination files of larger sizes. The randomness of contents in the destination does not affect me , but I cannot use /dev/zero as well.
Is there a way I can instruct dd command to repeatedly write the same input file till the destination is filled up?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use cat to get a larger output

```
cat randomfile1 randomfile2 randomfile1 ...
```

and only use the first n bytes you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a file random_1(10M) using dd,

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=./random_1 bs=1M count=10      # create a base file
```

and if you want a new file random_2(12M) then use the first file to create another file (random_1_1) and join them both,

```
dd if=./random_1 of=./ramdom_1_1 bs=1M count=2       # create a dummy 2M file

cat ramdom_1 random_1_1 > randrom_2                  # Join both files
```